# traceId / spanId generated are changed post WebClient call

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, reactor-netty

We are using ReactorNettyHttpTracing with our Spring Web + Spring WebFlux + Spring Cloud Sleuth application. The traceId / spanId generated are getting changed post the WebClient call.

> Spring Boot v2.6.1 and Spring Cloud v3.1.0

How do I retain the same traceId and spanId for the entire Spring Web request?

```
    @Bean
    public ReactorNettyHttpTracing reactorNettyHttpTracing(HttpTracing httpTracing) {
        return ReactorNettyHttpTracing.create(httpTracing);
    }

    WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(tracing.decorateHttpClient(httpClient)))
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .filters(exchangeFilters -> { 
                exchangeFilters.add(exchangeFilter.logRequest());
                exchangeFilters.add(exchangeFilter.logResponse());
            }).build();
```

Comment: Reported under https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed fixed in Sleuth 3.1.3

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do we have Sleuth in Spring Boot 3.x ? I was with the understanding that we need to move to Micrometer.

Comment: There's no Sleuth compatible version for Spring Boot 3. The problem is not present in Spring Boot 3 because we don't automatically instrument Reactor so that it injects trace identifiers in thread locals.